# Handle keyboard events in jsfiddle with THREE.js orbit controls

Tags: javascript, three.js, keyboard-events

SITUATION 1: [This simple jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huchengtw/Wk7jR/) works OK at handling keyboad events (after the user has clicked in the display panel of the jsfiddle).

SITUATION 2:- When I try to apply a similar method to this [larger jsfiddle using THREE.js with OrbitControls and shaders](http://jsfiddle.net/steveow/ssff6tha/) the key presses are not caught and may cause text characters to appear in the code areas of the jsfiddle.

Here is the relevant key handling code which I am using in the latter:-

```
function F_handleKeyDown(event) 
{
  if (event.keyCode === 66) 
  { 
    window.isBDown = true; //... 66 is "b"
    alert("Pressed b down");
  }
}

function F_handleKeyUp(event) 
{
  if (event.keyCode === 66) 
  {
    window.isBDown = false;
    alert("Released b up");
  }
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', F_handleKeyDown, false);
window.addEventListener('keyup'  , F_handleKeyUp  , false);

//... Tried, but didnt solve the problem.
//document.body.addEventListener('keydown', F_handleKeyDown, false);
//document.body.addEventListener('keyup'  , F_handleKeyUp  , false);

//... Tried, but didnt solve the problem.
//myContainer = document.getElementById('container');
//myContainer.addEventListener('keydown', F_handleKeyDown, false);
//myContainer.addEventListener('keyup'  , F_handleKeyUp  , false);
```

SITUATION 3:- When I apply the same code in a localserver .html file the keyboard events are caught OK.

**QUESTION**
So, in SITUATION 2 - the complex jsfiddle (with Orbit Controls active) - how do I get the javascript to catch keyboard events?

Comment: try canvas.addEventListener but i will always use window.addEventListener( 'keydown', onDocumentKeyDown, false ); or document.addEventListener(...)

Comment: @Martin. Thanks. I tried those but they had no obvious effect.